# what is an engraved portrait?

Tags: meaning

"Queen Victoria a fine engraved portrait showing the Queen in profile looking into a book. She is dressed in her familiar black (which she wore for the rest of her life after Albert died) with her white veil. Boldly signed underneath the image and dated in her hand 1877. This image came from the personal possessions of a Royal Lady in Waiting."

It is made of paper and looks like a black and white photo.

Comment: Most likely it means a reproduced image, produced by using a metal plate onto which the image was "engraved" (cut/carved using one of several different techniques).  The plate would then be inked and pressed against paper to transfer the image.  (The department of the US government that prints currency is known as the "Bureau of Engraving and Printing", since engraving is the technique used to reproduce currency.)

Answer (score 1):

[Engraving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engraving) is when you make a picture by carving it into a surface. So an engraved portrait would be a portrait made this way as opposed to a portrait that was painted or sketched.

Answer (score 0):

An **engraved** portrait is one that is signed, presumably by the person in the picture.  This is an older meaning not used as much now.

Answer (score 0):

Engraving is an ancient term for printing.  Hence from the book "All quiet on the western front".  A loose paraphrasing from the book "I had killed X the Engraver, I had killed a printer".